# How to get the access token to start or shut down VMs on azure classic portal?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

How to get the access token to start or shut down VMs on azure classic portal, I have tried multiple links for the same such as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication, also whatever access token I m getting using that I can only start, shutdown ARM vms, not classic VMs. Can somebody please help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm very lazy, so I'm using arm token to startup\shutdown classic vms :). sample code:

```
$header = @{ Authorization = "Bearer $token" }
$uri = "https://management.azure.com{0}/{1}?api-version={2}" -f $vmId, $action, $apiVer
Invoke-WebRequest -Headers $header -Method Post -Uri $uri -UseBasicParsing
```

to start use `$action = 'start'`
to shutdown use `$action = 'shutdown'`
for apiVersion use `$apiVer = '2017-04-01'`
for ID, just use classic VM resource id, example:

```
/subscriptions/GUID/resourceGroups/rgName/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/vmName
```

you would need to grant yourself (or the entity you are getting script on behalf of) proper rights. I'm using these:

```
"Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/read"
"Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/start/action"
"Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/shutdown/action"
"Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines/operationStatuses/read"
```

Comment: above solution worked like magic, I had tried many ways but none them were working. Thanks again. I have one more doubt, when I m posting API for shutdown, how should I keep resources provisioned? I can see that IP address is getting restored, does this mean by default this API call keeps resources provisioned?

Comment: if that helped you - you should mark it as an answer ;) but I'm not sure about your question, can you maybe rephrase it?